# Check if a user has a permission in pyramid (pylons 2)?

Tags: python, pylons, pyramid

How do i check if a user has a permission in pyramid.  For example, I want to show some HTML only if a user has some permission, but have the view available for everybody.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual method is:

```
from pyramid.security import has_permission
has_permission('view', someresource, request)
```

See also http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/narr/security.html#debugging-imperative-authorization-failures and http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/api/security.html#pyramid.security.has_permission

Comment: Why does this concept have to be tied directly to a request and view? Isn't it a common pattern to check a users persmission outside of a request/response cycle?