# Pyramid: Check for permission given a route name

Tags: python, python-2.7, permissions, pyramid

It is [not hard to check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916127/check-if-a-user-has-a-permission-in-pyramid-pylons-2) for permission of a certain resource in Pyramid. I would like to know how to determine the permission type and the resource corresponding to a certain route.

**Details.** Assume that I have added a route

```
config.add_route('resource.edit', '/t/{resource_id:\d+}/edit',
    factory = FactoryFactory('resource') ))
```

where `FactoryFactory` is a function returning a factory. In this case, it returns a factory for *"resources"*, whatever that may be. Later then, I go like this:

```
@view_config(
    route_name='resource.edit',
    renderer='resource-edit.pt',
    permission='edit'
)
def edit(resource_object, request):
    ...
```

At some point, I will generate an input element on the website which will link to

```
request.route_url('resource.edit', resource_id=some_input)
```

**Edit:** As requested, I will give you the exact template code hoping that this will give you a better understanding of the situation. The template engine we use is Chameleon.

```
    <a href="${request.route_url('resource.edit', resource_id=res.id)}" 
       class="btn btn-info morespacing"><i class="icon-edit"></i>edit</a>
```

Now what I would want is something like this:

```
    <a tal:condition="h.route_accessible(request, 'resource.edit', res.id)" 
       href="${request.route_url('resource.edit', resource_id=res.id)}" 
       class="btn btn-info morespacing"><i class="icon-edit"></i>edit</a>
```

In other words: I want to display this input element *only* if the user has permission to perform the edit operation in the first place.

---

Now, I can give you an example of what would work but is unappealing to me because it is inflexible. I code a helper function

```
def can_edit(request, factory_type, res_id):
    resource = FactoryFactory(factory_type)(res_id)
    return has_permission('edit', resource, request)
```

and then I write

```
    <a tal:condition="h.can_edit(request, 'resource', res.id)" 
       href="${request.route_url('resource.edit', resource_id=res.id)}" 
       class="btn btn-info morespacing"><i class="icon-edit"></i>edit</a>
```

This is unappealing to me because the information about the factory *and* the information about the permission has been coded into the route, so it feels to me that I should be able to access it by simply providing the name of the *route*.

---

Therefore, I am looking for a way to obtain the resource and the permission from *only* the route information, i.e. from the string `'resource.edit'` and the resource id `some_input`. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I read your question multiple times, I do not get your point. Most probably you look for a solution to a common problem. You are asking for an implementation detail, but you should explain your resource model using ACLs, users with permissions and demonstrate your problem at some URLs to illustrate the context.

Comment: There is really not much more to say ... I want a function which takes as input the name of a route (`'resource.edit'` in the above case), a resource id, and a request object and then returns `True` if the current user has permission to access that route or `False` if he does not.

Comment: Right now, you got 2 answers. Both seem not to help you that much. Could mean you did not explained your question very well. Add some view code and/or template code to show your problem. Do you want to start a bounty for every little helper function or get some advice to select the pyramid concepts that fit your problem domain?

Comment: I will add some template code for your convenience. However, please don't patronize. I have a very specific question, and it is not about pyramid concepts fitting my problem domain. It is a technical question concerning the determination of access rights given the name of a route which has been set up via `view_config`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To your question:

> Therefore, I am looking for a way to obtain the resource and the
>   permission from only the route information, i.e. from the string
>   'resource.edit' and the resource id some_input. Is this possible? If
>   yes, how?

Pyramid cannot know whether a user (current request) be able to access your resource before you provide one to it. You can reference to

[Assigning ACLs to your Resource Objects](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/security.html#assigning-acls-to-your-resource-objects)

As you can see, Pyramid will look into __ACL__ attributes of your resource object (and __ACL__ of resource's ancestor as well), then determine who has what kind of permissions to this resource, therefore, it is not possible with Pyramid default authorization policy.

To solve your problem, you can either customize the [AuthorizationPolicy](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/security.html#creating-your-own-authorization-policy), make your own authorization rule, or you can make creating the resource from ID easily.

Think about this, if you have an `owner` field of the corresponding table to the resource, and you need to check whether current user is the owner of specific resource, you will need to get that resource from database anyway. So you will need to create a resource which provides __ACL__ attributes anyway. So, my suggestion here is, make creating the resource much easier, make it something like this `Resource(res.id)`, so that you can write your template like this

```
<a tal:condition="has_permission('edit', Resource(res.id), request)" 
   href="${request.route_url('resource.edit', resource_id=res.id)}" 
   class="btn btn-info morespacing"><i class="icon-edit"></i>edit</a>
```

---

Update

Then I think what you need is to use introspector to get the factory and create the resource like this

```
def has_permission_for_route(request, route_name, permission, res_id):
    introspector = request.registry.introspector
    route_name = request.matched_route.name
    route_intr = introspector.get('routes', route_name)
    factory = route_intr['factory']

    resource = factory(request, res_id=res_id)
    return has_permission(permission, resource, request)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract the factory from route - use pyramid introspection

```
@view_config(route_name='bar')
def show_current_route_pattern(request):
    introspector = request.registry.introspector
    route_name = request.matched_route.name
    route_intr = introspector.get('routes', route_name)
    factory = route_intr['factory'])
    ...
```

Find more about introspection [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/introspector.html).

Comment: This looks very promising! Thanks a bunch =). I will accept Victor Lin's answer because it is more detailed, but I'll award the bounty to you, seeing that you posted about the introspector first.

Comment: I am glad you noticed that.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I update my answer an then noticed that you have already posted this

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: No, you do not obtain information about permission from a route. Routes just match views. Views and resources can be protected with permissions using lots of different ways. Your security policy is usually related to users, resources and views - not to routes.

May be this suggestion can be of any help to you.

Given this route to a resource

```
config.add_route('resource.view', '/t/{resource_id:\d+}',
    factory = FactoryFactory('resource') ))
```

you create a view to match this route. The route factory will manufacture the resource as a context. **Encapsulate permission related code inside the view**.

```
@view_config(
    route_name='resource.view',
    renderer='resource-view.pt',
    permission='view'
)
def view_page(resource_object, request):
    can_edit = has_permission('edit', resource_object, request)

    #do some more stuff - extend the dictionary passed to the renderer
    ...

    return dict(
        res = resource_object,
        can_edit = can_edit,
    )
```

Inside your template you use 'can_edit' to control visibility of this link or any other markup.

```
<a tal:condition="can_edit"
   href="${request.route_url('resource.edit', resource_id=res.id)}" 
   class="btn btn-info morespacing"><i class="icon-edit"></i>edit</a>
```

You could improve the example by computing the URL to edit the resource in view code as well.

```
@view_config(
    route_name='resource.view',
    renderer='resource-view.pt',
    permission='view'
)
def view_page(resource_object, request):
    can_edit = has_permission('edit', resource_object, request)
    edit_url = request.route_url('resource.edit', resource_id=resource_object.id)

    #do some more stuff - extend the dictionary passed to the renderer
    ...

    return dict(
        can_edit = can_edit,
        edit_url = edit_url,
    )
```

This leads to compact template code and improves testability of view code.

```
<a tal:condition="can_edit" 
   href="${edit_url}" 
   class="btn btn-info morespacing"><i class="icon-edit"></i>edit</a>
```

To make the code more common to any pyramid developer I want to use the framework option to   acquire the context from the request.

```
@view_config(
    route_name='resource.view',
    renderer='resource-view.pt',
    permission='view'
)
def view_page(request):
    context = request.context
    can_edit = has_permission('edit', context, request)
    edit_url = request.route_url('resource.edit', resource_id=context.id)

    #do some more stuff - extend the dictionary passed to the renderer
    ...

    return dict(
        can_edit = can_edit,
        edit_url = edit_url,
    )
```

Regarding your application I want to recommend these pyramid sample apps:

- [Hybridauth](https://github.com/Pylons/hybridauth)
- [Pyramid Auth Demo](https://github.com/mmerickel/pyramid_auth_demo)
- maybe you like this: pyramid.security.view_execution_permitted

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used...

http://ziggurat-foundations.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Within this you can easily test for specific user permissions, so then either in your template or your code you can easily filter a user permission.

```
t = session.query(UserPermission).\
    filter(UserPermission.user_id == 'userid').\
    filter(UserPermission.perm_name == 'yourpermission')).first()
```

Then in the template (Jinja2 example shown) you can do:

```
{% if t %}
    <!-- show edit link -->
{% endif %}
```

Or if you are doing a user query you can just tie a join in with your current query.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that does look interesting: However, it does not really solve the problem in so far as that I still have to specify the permission in two places, once in the view_config and once when defining `t`. Whether or not the user has permission to visit a certain link only depends on his ID and the route name, so it should be possible to extract that information somehow from this datum.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the permission on the resource (persistent or just as attr of the class):

```
def dynamic_resource_permission(context, request):
    permission = getattr(context, 'view_permission', 'view')
    if not has_permission(context, permission):
        raise HTTPForbidden()
    return True

@view_config(
  route_name='resource.edit',
  renderer='resource-edit.pt',
  permission='edit',
  custom_predicates=(dynamic_resource_permission,),
)
def edit(resource_object, request):
    ....
```

PS: I haven't ran the above, but some variant of the above should work.

Comment: How will this help me to not *display* the link to a forbidden route? In fact, what does this change at all? When someone without permission attempts to resolve that route, a HTTPForbidden is raised anyway.